# While using container managed entity bean when is the bean stored to database by the container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, entity, containers

While using container managed entity bean when is the bean stored to database by the container?
Can this be controlled inside the servlet using some code statements or the container manages this automatically internally?

Comment: Are you talking about JPA entities, or about old EJB2 entity beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is stored to the database when your transaction is committed.

With CMP you can control this with transaction demarcation in the deplyment descriptor a'la

```
<ejb-jar>
...
<assembly-descriptor>
...
<container-transaction>
<method>
<ejb-name>EmployeeRecord</ejb-name>
<method-name>*</method-name>
</method>
<trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
</container-transaction>
<container-transaction>
<method>
<ejb-name>EmployeeRecord</ejb-name>
<method-name>updatePhoneNumber</method-name>
</method>
<trans-attribute>Mandatory</trans-attribute>
</container-transaction>
...
```

This is a snippet from the spec http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-2.1-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/ejb-2_1-fr-spec.pdf

When you invoke a method on an ejb a new transaction may be initiated by the container, depending on your demarcation, and if the method terminates successfully, the transaction may be committed, depending on this-and-that. For instance if your specific method was demarcated with requires-new, it *will* be committed, because it has it's own transaction, but if it is demarcated with requires, and was called within an aready running transaction (for instance because it was called from a session bean method demarcated with, say, requires or requires-new), it will be committed when that enclosing transaction is committed. Or if it fails, not only the changes made inside that method will be rolled back, but also changes made inside the enclosing method call/transaction.

While the deployment descriptor may allow for nested transactions, it actually boils down to how the database engine handles transactions in the end. Very often rdbms doesn't really support nested transactions, but instead uses transaction savepoints, so what appears as recursive from the ejb-perspective may actually happen in a "linear" fashion in the database. In most scenarios the result is the same, though.

It may also be relevant to consider transaction isolation level.

Comment: So if the server crashes before transaction is committed the entity state is lost?

Comment: @seahorse Yes, unless it is stored elsewhere. from the spec (again): If the state of an entity was being updated by a transaction at the time the container crashed, the entity’s state is automatically reset to the state of the last committed transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The bean state is guaranteed to be saved to the database when the transaction is committed. Usually, the container will wait until commit time before saving the state, in order to avoid unnecessary updates in case the transaction rolls back, or in case the state is modified several times in a single transaction.

The spec also says that the container must make sure that modifications made to entity beans are visible by an EJBQL queryexecuted in the same transaction. That means that the modifications are saved to the database before an EJBQL finder is executed.

Comment: If the query runs inside the same session/connection as the changes were, they are visible to that query, even if the updates aren't committed yet. What are visible outside that session/transaction depends on the transaction isolation level.